# Export CSV from Mainframe DB2 in batch mode

Tags: db2, mainframe, zos, isql, db2-zos

how can I export in a CSV file the result of a SELECT query from Mainframe DB2 in Batch mode?
I have tried the FILE MANAGER online mode and it works but I need to use the batch mode for a better performance. 
I can also use ISQL but I don't know which parameters I have to use to create a CSV file.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails and you don't mind a little programming then coding your own program that runs the query and writes CSV is EXTREMELY easy.

I mention this because this might be better for you than relying on some tool.

Answer (score 0):

As you're looking for improved performance I'd suggest you CALL the DSNUTILU stored procedure with the UNLOAD utility using DELIMITED COLDEL ',' and SHRLEVEL CHANGE ISOLATION UR parameters for CSV and to maximise concurrency on your DB2 for z/OS table. There are many other option depending on your requirements.

For reference refer to [DSNUTILU stored procedure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sp_dsnutilu.html) and [Syntax and options of the UNLOAD control statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/ugref/src/tpc/db2z_unloadsyntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

On iserie you have the CPYTOIMPF command, may be on zos too